# The listings package is rendering an empty frame

Tags: listings

The markup

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl}

\section{Statement of problem}

\subsection{Secondary Problem}

\begin{lstlisting}
    foo = 'Ren\'{e}'
    parse upper var foo bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

displays an empty frame both with frame=single and with frame=trbl.

Comment: Remove the `draft` option.

Comment: Thanks; that did it. If you put it in an answer I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

The `listings` package has a `draft` option (that is also collected from the global `draft` you pass to `\documentclass`).

If you want your listing to show either remove the `draft` key from `\documentclass` or add the `final` key to `\usepackage{listings}`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[final]{listings}
% hyperref should be loaded last with only a few exceptions
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Rexx, extendedchars=true, frame=trbl}

\section{Statement of problem}

\subsection{Secondary Problem}

\begin{lstlisting}
    foo = 'Ren\'{e}'
    parse upper var foo bar
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```